# How do I fix DLL Load Failed with the NAOBOT

Tags: python, python-2.7, nao-robot

I've set the environment path for the NAO SDK as

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\pynaoqi-python2.7-2.8.7.4-win64-vs2015-20210818_210634\lib\

however, when I come to import naoqi on python.

I get

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Can anyone help me with this.

I am on Windows 10 and using Python 2.7.11 32bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a PyNAOqi built for 64-bits systems with a Python installation built for 32-bits system. You must install a 64-bits version of Python.